# DI container with multiple instances of same object

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, php

I'm looking for idea to make a DI container that can store multiple instances of the same object. Usually, a DI container should store either a single instance of the object, or create new object each time it gets requested. Here's example I'm working on:

```
class Container {
    protected $store;

    public function get($alias) {
         if (isset($this -> store[$alias])) {
             return $this -> store[$alias]($this);
         }
    }

    public function bind($alias, Closure $obj) {
         $this -> store[$alias] = $obj;
    }
}
```

This all works well, for this case:

```
$c = new Container();
$c -> bind('book', function() {
    return new Book();
});

$book = $c -> get('book');
```

Now imagine I have class "Catalog", which behavior is dictated by parameters passed to it's constructor:

```
class Catalog {
    protected $category;

    public function __construct($category) {
        $this -> category = $category;    
    }
}
```

I want only single instance of each category stored in container. Yes i can do this easily by

```
$c -> bind('catalog.magazines', function() {
    return new Catalog('magazines');
});

$c -> bind('catalog.books', function() {
    return new Catalog('books');
});
```

But categories can be dynamically created at runtime, and this seems like a lot of code. Is there a convenient solution for this? Only one instance of each object and can handle them dynamically. Or maybe it's not DI at all?

Comment: I think you're talking about lazy initialization. DI containers I know of do that by default. See [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/) ([lazy injection](http://php-di.org/doc/lazy-injection.html)), [Symfony DI](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html) ([lazy services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/lazy_services.html))

Comment: If these objects can be created at runtime then you're talking about value objects (you can't create behaviour) and you don't need DI for them. DI is dealing with abstract dependencies. `Catalog(Books)` and `Catalog(Magazines)` will always be objects of the same **class** and if they collaborate with some value objects they shouldn't really need them to be instantiated and fully operational in abstract sense ($catalog->giveMeSomethingToRead() may return false).

Answer (score 1):

> But categories can be dynamically created at runtime, and this seems
>   like a lot of code. Is there a convenient solution for this? Only one
>   instance of each object and can handle them dynamically. Or maybe it's
>   not DI at all?

Well, if categories can be dynamically created, how are you going to identify and get from DI container?

I think you should not put categories /catalogs / whatever into container if they are really mass-created at runtime dynamically. Instead you might want to put CategoryCollection into container and add / query / remove collections from it using any criteria you want.

Isn't that what you want?